# SQL: JOIN multiple rows depending on values in multiple rows

Tags: sql, select, join, case

I'd like to SELECT from a table and JOIN three rows using CASE statements. I'm more used to C++ where it would be an IF statement, here in bad pseudo-code (where this applies to any of the to-be-joined rows, ie if any of the to-be-joined rows has ...)

```
IF (value1 == 1) // IF any of the rows have value1 == 1
{
    value1 = 1;
    value2 = 0;
}
ELSE IF (value1 == 0 && value2 == 1) // IF all of the rows have value1 == 0 and any have value2 == 1 
{
    value1 = 0;
    value2 = 1;
}
```

so for example if the three rows look like as follows (IDs have  to be identical, don't ask me why...)

```
ID    value1  value2
--------------------
 1      1       0
 1      0       0
 1      0       1
```

I would like the resulting joined row to be

```
 1      1       0
```

however, if the three original rows look like

```
ID    value1  value2
--------------------
 1      0       0
 1      0       0
 1      0       1
```

then I would like the resulting joined row to be

```
 1      0       1
```

I'm sorry for the shoddy table formatting, I'm not used to markup. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. Speed should not really be an issue as never more than three rows will have to be joined per query.

Comment: About your *shoddy formatting* : just simply indent your lines by 4 spaces (or highlight the lines and press the "code samples" button `{  }` on the toolbar) to get those formatted properly

Comment: It could illustrate your goal better if you used other numbers in value1 and value2.  When everything is a one or a zero, it is not as easy to discern what you are aiming for.

Comment: I thought 1 and 0 would be most clear, what should I use, maybe some complex numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a `JOIN` at all, it seems that you need to aggregate your results following your logic. It would be nice to know what RDBMS you are using, but this should work on most of them:

```
SELECT  ID,
        Value1,
        CASE WHEN Value1 = 1 THEN 0 ELSE Value2 END Value2
FROM (  SELECT  ID,
                MAX(CASE WHEN Value1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Value1,
                MAX(Value2) Value2
        FROM YourTable
        GROUP BY ID) A
```

Comment: Thanks a million, that worked like a charm :) (I'll also keep that formatting in mind)